# Xcode : Passing Data between view controller

Tags: delegates

I have A Table View Controller containing names (as example A, B, C, etc,,,).
If I pressed on one cell, it should be shifting to another B View Controller with the 2 numbers (a, b).

and on the name cell, it should appear the value of c = (a + b) in the subtitle.

On B class, i create a protocol in order to send to A a NSDictionary.
and from A, i can access these Data without any problem from A

I am just cannot solve how to insert the value of c in the subtitle of the same cell which I clicked.

for example, when i press on A name1, i switch to second view controller, So, i put values for a = 2 and b = 6 and click on save, I got the value c = a + b = 8.
I want to have name1 and under the value of 8.

I tried to reload data for table view, but didn't work.

Where shall I write some codes in order to make the subtitle with the value c appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"text";
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"description text";
}
```

Comment: I tried didSelectRowAtIndexPath, Finaly It works )) thanks man